# Why would this dataset implementation run out of memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I follow [this instruction](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) and write the following code to create a Dataset for images([COCO2014 training set](http://msvocds.blob.core.windows.net/coco2014/train2014.zip))

```py
from pathlib import Path
import tensorflow as tf


def image_dataset(filepath, image_size, batch_size, norm=True):
    def preprocess_image(image):
        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
        image = tf.image.resize(image, image_size)
        if norm:
            image /= 255.0  # normalize to [0,1] range
        return image

    def load_and_preprocess_image(path):
        image = tf.read_file(path)
        return preprocess_image(image)

    all_image_paths = [str(f) for f in Path(filepath).glob('*')]
    path_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_image_paths)
    ds = path_ds.map(load_and_preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size = len(all_image_paths))
    ds = ds.repeat()
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    ds = ds.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    return ds

ds = image_dataset(train2014_dir, (256, 256), 4, False)
image = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next('images')
# image is then fed to the network
```

This code will always run out of both memory(32G) and GPU(11G) and kill the process. Here is the messages shown on terminal.
[image]

I also spot that the program get stuck at `sess.run(opt_op)`. Where is wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: I think your `path_ds.map` function is taking up way to much space in memory, leaving little room for `shuffle` to do its job. Personally, when it comes to training on image datasets I prefer to use generators, which can help control how much RAM your preprocessing function uses. You might also want to run this on a smaller dataset just to see if you are getting the same error.

Comment: I've tried a smaller dataset as you suggested, but suffering NaN error at `tf.clip_by_global_norm)`...I'm now trying to figure out why this happens. Do you have any idea how to make `map` works without changing dataset?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is this:

```py
ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size = len(all_image_paths))
```

The buffer that `Dataset.shuffle()` uses is an 'in memory' buffer so you are effectively trying to load the whole dataset in memory.

You have a couple of options (which you can combine) to fix this:

#### Option 1:

Reduce the buffer size to a much smaller number.

#### Option 2:

Move the `shuffle()` statment before the `map()` statement.

This means we would be shuffling **before** we load the images therefore we'd just be storing the filenames in the memory buffer for the shuffle rather than storing huge tensors.